# Parsing JSON objects error

Tags: objective-c, json

I have this JSON.

```
{
"cnt": 1,
"list": [
    {
        "object1": [
            {
                "subobject1": "value1",
                "subobject2": "value2",
                "subobject3": "value3"
            }
        ],
        "object2": {
            "subobject1": value1,
            "subobject1": value2,
            "subobject1": value3
        }
    }
]
```

}

I can't get data from the first object. I receive an error

```
-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa281f82520
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa281f82520'
```

For the other object I get the data and I can see it in the NSLOG, but can't understand what's the problem with the first one and why the app is crashing.

This is how I parse the json in the DataModel

```
NSError *deserializationError;
        NSMutableDictionary  *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &deserializationError];

        NSArray * responseArr = json[@"list"];

        NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if(responseArr && [responseArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

            for(NSDictionary *cDictionary in responseArr) {
                DAObject *cty = [[DAObject alloc] initWithDictionary:ctyDictionary];

                if(cty) {
                    [result addObject:cty];
                }

            }

        }
```

then In the Object .m file

```
DAServiceObject *object1 = [[DAServiceObject alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary[@"object1"]];
self.value1 = object1.value1;
self.value2 = object1.value2;
```

and the app crashes.

Comment: is it on purpose that your objects aren't similar ? First one is an array while the second is an object (although both are technically objects, this is quite a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misinterpreted the data structure: "list" contains an array with only one item, i.e. a dictionary. This dictionary contains an array for each key (e.g. "item1"), again with only one item (again a dictionary).

**edit**

```
// ...
if(responseArr && [responseArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSDictionary *content = responseArr[0];
    for (NSSString *key in [content allKeys]) {
        NSDictionary *a = content[key][0];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I understood. So how can I parse this? Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is not an array. It is a dictionary. It's a dictionary with one key "cnt" and one key "list". The object under key "list" is an array.